# Tools to determine video orientation

Tags: android, ffmpeg, exiftool, mediainfo

I receive videos from different devices and want to encode them using the correct orientation.

I've seen some of examples of how to determine the orientation of a video from a iPhone.

With exiftool and mediainfo I can indeed tell if an iPhone video has to be rotated.

However, for android videos, both portrait and landscape videos have the same rotation and matrix structure as each other.

Maybe this is just with my phone, I'm trying to find videos taken from newer droid phones.

My question however is whether there's other tools or a different way to determine the orientation that'll work with all devices.

EDIT:
I just checked a video from a Samsung Galaxy S II, and I can get the orientation from exiftool. So it's not a problem with all android phones. 
My android phone is a HTC Desire running on android 2.2.

And actually (I didn't even notice before) a portrait video will not be correctly oriented even when playing on the phone. So I guess it's not about the tools, the orientation data just doesn't seem to be correct at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some phones include the rotation information, some phone don't, but the best way to know on videos that include this information is with mediainfo:

```
mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Rotation%"
```